# jQuery 2 decimal places and round up

Tags: javascript, rounding, tofixed

Is there a way to round number like: 0.203 to 0.21

Now I do this:

```
priceCurrent.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Comment: This should be tagged [tag:javascript]. Of course if JS already has a good way to do it jquery doesn't need to provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You multiply this number with 100, take the `ceil` and divide by 100

```js
console.log(Math.ceil(0.203*100)/100)
```

Comment: With all the floating point pitfalls. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary#comment28913957_17083793 for example.i

Comment: @user202729, of course, I didn't handle all the cases here but specifically gave the user an idea about how he can begin solving this.